# What are the colored bars?

Tags: guitar-hero-warriors-rock

I was playing Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock for XBOX 360, and when I added a second guitar / player, during the concert, one player had the normal notes flowing down, but the other player had these strange color bars.   The bars flow down to the music, and it seems like you have to press the buttons a certain way, but it was a little confusing.

Just wondering if someone can explain these, and hopefully point me to an explanation.   I expected the second player to get bass notes, or other guitar notes, not these strange color bars.

I found a picture that shows the bars, its the third one from the left with no notes showing.  Notice how they are thick, colorful, dithered.     In the game, they appear to change colors, I assume meaning you have to press different buttons...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [open bass notes.](http://guitarhero.wikia.com/wiki/Bass_Guitar#Open_Note)  You strum without holding any fret buttons down.

> In Guitar Hero: World Tour and onwards a new type of note is present: the open note. The open note is purple in appearance and spreads across the highway. Because it doesn't match up to a target the open note is played without holding any fret buttons. Open notes can also be hammered-on. Hammer on open notes appear white. The open note can be considered the easiest type of note to hit but can be difficult when played along with regular colored notes.
>
> Another modified form of the open note exists in Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock. This is the open sustain. The open sustain is played just like a regular open note. Since no buttons correspond to it, no buttons must be held to sustain it.

Comment: I will try again, but it seemed like you have to hold at least one button down.   In fact, it seemed to work best when holding down all 4 buttons, because holding the same button did not work all the time...

Comment: SO, I am not sure if they are 'open notes', but I did partially figure it out - they show up if you are set to 'beginner' level.  In easy, medium, etc. you get the normal notes.  When you choose beginner, you see these bars (maybe open notes).  I found the same thing happens in a couple other guitar hero games (van halen and metallica).

Comment: @ScottSzretter That is because open notes are considered to be easy.  Each difficulty has its own note chart.  Sometimes the harder notes are replaced by easier notes.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a 'kick' on the drums.. Like the pedal that you kick/tap/step with your foot.